# multiple variable on JSON array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have JSON array like this

```
"Data":[  
   {  
      "Amount":"000000069840",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00002084-00000030",
      "Periode":"201711"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000060321",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00002111-00000027",
      "Periode":"201712"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000057148",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00002137-00000026",
      "Periode":"201801"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000031021",
      "Denda":"00000000",
      "kubikasi":"00002154-00000017",
      "Periode":"201802"
   }
]
```

but in some case when I parse I have like this

```
"Data":[  
   {  
      "Amount":"000000018226",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00003855-00000012",
      "Periode":"201710"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000012225",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00003864-00000009",
      "Periode":"201711"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000025315",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00003879-00000015",
      "Periode":"201712"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000037130",
      "Denda":"00002500",
      "kubikasi":"00003899-00000020",
      "Periode":"201801"
   },
   {  
      "Amount":"000000013500",
      "Denda":"00000000",
      "kubikasi":"00003909-00000010",
      "Periode":"201802"
   }
],
```

and some case I have single array on array "Data".

How can I get that value and show it?

Comment: Create a POJO class and map the json property to `ArrayList<POJOClass>`. The answer would be too long to post as the question is not really clear. Where and how you want to show the data?

Comment: i want show all object on that array, and show to next activity

Comment: How do you want to show? in a `ListView`?

Comment: **[This post](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/865878/Problem-in-Using-GSON-to-parse-Java-to-populate-a)** might help you.

Comment: no on @TextView, actualy in single array i already can show that on text view but on some case when i parse the json i found problem like this and i can't show them to my TextView

Comment: You get any error?

Comment: no but the output show just one array

Comment: after getting response. create you textview programatically. so whatever the length of array is, your textview will get increased

Comment: Bit confusing.. Could you post screenshot of your problem?

Comment: can u show me how to made that?

Answer (score 0):

Use google `gson` library, add below line in gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

then create a POJO

```
class Data{
  @SerializedName("Amount")
  private String amount;
  @SerializedName("Denda")
  private String denda;
  @SerializedName("kubikasi")
  private String kubikasi;
  @SerializedName("Periode")
  private String periode;
  // getters and setters
}

class Response{
  @SerializedName("Data")
  private ArrayList<Data> data;
}
```

Now,

```
String responseString  = [your json array];
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString,Response.class);
```